# Align vdots in equation

Tags: align, mathtools

I want my vdots to fall under the expressions and not at the end as its now.

[image]

I found solutions online for equations by using &=, but this is not applicable for me because I don't use the equal sign. My code is

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
(U_1^{(1)},U_2^{(1)}, \dots U_k^{(1)}) \\
(U_1^{(2)},U_2^{(2)}, \dots U_k^{(2)}) \\
\vdotswithin{=} \\
(U_1^{(N)},U_2^{(N)}, \dots U_k^{(N)})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

How can I change this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ampersand symbol (`&`) is not limited to being used in conjunction with the equals sign.

Try this:

```
     \begin{align*}
    (U_1^{(1)},U_2^{(1)}, &\dots U_k^{(1)}) \\
    (U_1^{(2)},U_2^{(2)}, &\dots U_k^{(2)}) \\
    & \vdots \\
    (U_1^{(N)},U_2^{(N)}, &\dots U_k^{(N)})
    \end{align*}
```

which produces this:

[image]

You can place the `&` symbol wherever you want the alignment to occur.

Comment: Thank you. I've used &= so many times and always believed it had to be used together. So many new possibilities opened up now.

Answer (score 4):

Use this for an automatic placement (and a simpler code):

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  (U_1^{(1)},U_2^{(1)}, & \dots U_k^{(1)}) \\
  (U_1^{(2)},U_2^{(2)}, & \dots, U_k^{(2)}) \\[-0.5ex]
                        & \vdotswithin{ \dots } \\[-0.5ex] % change the 120 mu value for appropriate position
  (U_1^{(N)},U_2^{(N)}, & \dots, U_k^{(N)})
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. I remove an unnecessary space ;) There's also `\shortvdotswithin` if anyone prefers it.

Comment: `shortvdots within`gives a bad vertical spacing for me (too tight above, too large below), but maybe I miss something.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the vertical dots to be horizontally centred under the equations, rather than being aligned with any particular alignment point, then the environment you need is not `{align*}` or `{aligned}`, but rather `{gather*}`, another one of the displayed equation structures offered by [the amsmath package](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
(U_1^{(1)},U_2^{(1)}, \dots U_k^{(1)}) \\
(U_1^{(2)},U_2^{(2)}, \dots U_k^{(2)}) \\
\vdots \\
(U_1^{(N)},U_2^{(N)}, \dots U_k^{(N)})
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For novice users of the math environments of the `amsmath` package, you may want to add that with the `gather` and `gather*` environments, *all rows* will be centered, not just the row that contains the `\vdots` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use an environment such as `align`, you should provide indications where the alignment should take place. No natural optimal alignment point appears to be available, so I suggest you make the first `,` (comma) the common alignment point. Your `\vdotswithin{=}` directive seems to be a bit out of place, as there is no `=` symbol to align on. I suggest you use a simple `&\vdots` construct instead.

Separately, there seems to be no need to nest an `aligned` environment inside an `equation*` environment; I suggest you use a single `align*` environment instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
(U_1^{(1)}&,U_2^{(1)}, \dots, U_k^{(1)}) \\
(U_1^{(2)}&,U_2^{(2)}, \dots, U_k^{(2)}) \\
&\vdots \\
(U_1^{(N)}&,U_2^{(N)}, \dots, U_k^{(N)})
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using `\mspace` command, but it requires manulally adjusting the position of `\vdots`.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{book} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document} 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
(U_1^{(1)},U_2^{(1)}, \dots U_k^{(1)}) \\
(U_1^{(2)},U_2^{(2)}, \dots U_k^{(2)}) \\
\vdotswithin{\mspace{120mu}} \\ % change the 120 mu value for appropriate position
(U_1^{(N)},U_2^{(N)}, \dots U_k^{(N)})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]